# how to get windows URL every time page is loaded in electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

I am using electron-forge to create an app with node.js.

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1030,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  //mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
  mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
 /// mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();


  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

How can I detect the URL changed and find out the URL with the electron? let's say:

if the URL is [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), I want to pop up a modal saying "Please search here" with some message in the Electron app.

Please help! Thanks in advance and happy holidays to you guys!